# why meteor run only administrator on windows 10

Tags: windows, meteor

i ran `$ metor` on windows 10 but another drive and i have error

```
W20170209-23:17:53.763(3.5)? (STDERR) module.js:327
W20170209-23:17:53.764(3.5)? (STDERR)     throw err;
W20170209-23:17:53.765(3.5)? (STDERR)     ^
W20170209-23:17:53.765(3.5)? (STDERR) 
W20170209-23:17:53.766(3.5)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
W20170209-23:17:53.766(3.5)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
W20170209-23:17:53.766(3.5)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
W20170209-23:17:53.767(3.5)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
W20170209-23:17:53.767(3.5)? (STDERR)     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
W20170209-23:17:53.768(3.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Developing\Programming\Web\Tuto
rial\Meteor\myapp2\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:1:75)
W20170209-23:17:53.768(3.5)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
W20170209-23:17:53.769(3.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
W20170209-23:17:53.769(3.5)? (STDERR)     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
W20170209-23:153.770(3.5)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
W20170209-23:17:53.770(3.5)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

and so on but when i ran this code in c:\ and in administrator mode i don't have any error

**PS:**

Junction don't work to `AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules`

[image: windows 10 error]

**Update:**
don't need use administrator mode

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is causing your error, but when I used to develop using Meteor on a windows machine, I was able to solve the same error by uninstalling and then re-installing Meteor.

Hope that helps